# how can I do ajax call to fetch data from database in jsp using Extjs?

Tags: java, ajax, json, jsp, extjs

I am using Extjs framwork. First I create a servlet to get data from database. After getting data from database I am storing in a list. Then I am converting the list into json array.Now I want to get these data into jsp page using Extjs ajax call. how can I do that?
My servlet is

```
String str = "select * from employee";
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(str);
                    List<Employee> list1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
                    while(rs.next){
                        emp = new Employee();
                        emp.setEmpId(rs.getInt(1));
                        emp.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
                        list1.add(emp);
                    }
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list1, new TypeToken<List<Employee>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
```

Now I am calling this servlet in jsp file on click of button through Extjs. How can I do ajax call? I am using this..

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'click',
        handler: function () {  
            Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: 'TestEmployee',
       success: function(result, request) {
      /////what shold I do here so that I get data here and display in jsp???
   },
   failure: function(response, opts) {
      Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText);
   }
});
        },   
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()

    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var array = Ext.decode(result.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of ExtJs are you using?

I recommend you to use Ext 4 so you can use MVC pattern.

I would try to render the list of employees in a grid,  therefore I would do the ajax request through store.load() where the store would be bound to the grid.

This are basic tutorials of Extjs 4

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/getting_started

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#/guide/application_architecture

Best regards.